# formatting mobile number in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'am trying to get from user mobile number but its seems is not working? And I tried to make it required in the code and database but nothing happened

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A valid Mobile Number is required")]
       [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:940-05#-#######}")]
        public int MobileNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: Don't store phone numbers as numeric data types.

Comment: show your code to get it from database. and as per your format it looks like you should have it as string

Comment: I make it as string and its work fine. but the format not working? @viveknuna

Comment: @kono what do you mean by not working?

Comment: I want the phone number to be in this format (940-05#-#######) but when I test it I  enter any random no matter the length its accepted which wrong. @viveknuna

Comment: you can use `MaxLength` data annotation

Comment: That format may specify a valid phone number, but does not specify a valid integer